# How to fix Facebook Add to Cart Pixel Firing Issue?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-pixel

I am working for one of my client , which needs to track users who add items to cart , and didnt buy it ..

The Site uses BigCommerce , So the Add to Cart is performed Dynamically on Page without moving to next page .

Here is code for AddtoCart

```html
<div class="form-action">
  <input id="form-action-addToCart" data-wait-message="Adding to cart…" class="button button--primary" type="submit" value="Add to Cart">
</div>
```

And for facebook pixel :

```js
 

<!-- Add Pixel Events to the button's click handler -->

<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#form-action-addToCart').click(function() {
        fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
          content_name: 'Really Fast Running Shoes', 
          content_category: 'Apparel & Accessories > Shoes',
          content_ids: ['1234'],
          content_type: 'product',
          value: 4.99,
          currency: 'USD' 
        });  
      });
</script>
```

Also , tried Using $('input#form-action-addToCart') , but pixel didnt get fired .. I am using Facebook Official Pixel Chrome Extension ...

[image: facebook pixel - addtocart error]

Comment: need answer, please look into it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036938/do-we-need-to-explicitly-check-that-user-is-coming-from-facebook-or-not

Comment: I have fixed it myself , anyway thank you

Comment: hi @Srinivas08 can you please explain your answer? i have similar issue in my project

Comment: @sarathravi pls check the answer below, I added some more details to it... Let me knw if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , after some research , Finally got it working .. !

What we are doing here, is triggering the pixel on button or element click, rather than page load, which we do usually. As not all websites, might have separte page for every action, and some actions might be there in that page itself, like Add to Cart, Delete and more. So, we need to perform action on and trigger pixel.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#form-action-addToCart" ).click(function() {
-- Your Pixel Code Here --
};
</script>
```

Replace #form-action-addToCart with id of the element, for which you want the the pixel to be triggered.

Comment: need answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036938/do-we-need-to-explicitly-check-that-user-is-coming-from-facebook-or-not

Comment: @Srinivas08 how? i have the same problem

Comment: posted the answer above

Comment: It says page not found

Comment: @dominotrix above means, not in comment.. check the answers